# iOS NavigationPage.SetBackButton not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, navigation, hide

Above mentioned solution is not working for my project in iOS , [image: NavigationPage.SetBackButton](this,"false") can you please help me to sort out the issue . Screenshot attached for your reference. How to hide back button in navigation bar xamarin forms

Comment: Please, Put code not image of code inside your post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide back button text in Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52380257/hide-back-button-text-in-xamarin)

Comment: Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50962728/removing-back-arrow-in-navigation-bar-keeping-back-button-title)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the title of this page, set a SetBackButton on the page you want to return to.

You can add the following code to the page's constructor to hide the back button:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false);
```